# subdomain redirection problem in php

Tags: php, http

I am creating subdomains dynamically through the php script. This is creating well. But when I try to open it I am getting a default cgi error page ( http://subdomain.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi). But after 15-20 minutes later this is working fine. Why is this?

My subdomain creation code is below:

```
function subd($host, $port, $ownername, $passw, $request) {
    $authstr = "cpanel_userid:cpanel_password";

    $sock = fsockopen('localhost',2082);

    if(!$sock) {
        print('Socket error');
        exit();
    }

    $pass = base64_encode($authstr); 

    $in = "GET $request\r\n";
    $in .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $in .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
    $in .= "Authorization: Basic $pass\r\n";
    $in .= "\r\n";

    fputs($sock, $in);

    while (!feof($sock)) {
        $result .= fgets ($sock,128);
    }

    fclose( $sock );

    return $result;
}
```

I'm calling this function from my code. My subdomain is creating well but this is taking a bit more time to setup properly. Where am I going wrong? My server is running Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to dynamically create a subdomain. Also, please tell us your software stack (OS, daemons, etc). Lastly, tell us the error code you are getting. Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: Well, have you tried to contact to webmaster@subdomain.mydomain.com?

Comment: I have editied plz see again my subdomain creation code is abve.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that your web hoster needs the time to completely setup the subdomain. Looks normal to me.

Comment: Agreed. As an example, my hosting provider updates DNS configuration every 15 minutes.